# How to change partition columns in delta live tables?

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I first setup a delta live tables using Python as follow

```py
@dlt.table
def transaction():
  return (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .schema(transaction_schema)
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
    .load(path)
  )
```

And I wrote the delta live table to target database `test`

```json
{
    "id": <id>,
    "clusters": [
        {
            "label": "default",
            "autoscale": {
                "min_workers": 1,
                "max_workers": 5
            }
        }
    ],
    "development": true,
    "continuous": false,
    "edition": "core",
    "photon": false,
    "libraries": [
        {
            "notebook": {
                "path": <path>
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "dev pipeline",
    "storage": <storage>,
    "target": "test"
}
```

Everything worked as expected in the first trial.

After a while, I noticed that I forgot to add a partition column to the table, so I dropped the table in `test` by `DROP TABLE test.transaction`, and updated the notebook to

```py
@dlt.table(
  partition_cols=["partition"],
)
def transaction():
  return (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .schema(transaction_schema)
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
    .load(path)
    .withColumn("partition", F.to_date("timestamp"))
  )
```

However, when I ran the pipeline again, I got an error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot change partition columns for table transaction.
Current: 
Requested: partition
```

Looks like I can't change the partition column by only dropping the target table.

What is the proper way to change partition columns in delta live tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have changed the partitioning schema, then instead of starting pipeline using `Start` button, you need to select "Full refresh" option from the dropdown of the `Start` button:

[image]